# Datediff function adds startdate day also to the output

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have a report in Report Builder 1.0 wherein I have written a formula that calculates the number of days between startdate and enddate. For that I have used a `DATEDIFF` function in such a manner:

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, TODAY(), column from table which has end date)
```

Suppose, if today's date is  `1 July 2013`  & the column is sending end date as `10 July 2013`, then the `DATEDIFF` function is returning "10 days" whereas it should return output as value "9 days". Why is it returning 10 days rather than 9?

Answer (score 0):

Execute this in Sql Server and you get 9 days:

```
select DATEDIFF(day, '2013-07-01', '2013-07-10')
```

Using this as a dataset:

```
select CAST('2013-07-01' AS DateTime) AS StartDate, CAST('2013-07-10 23:59:59' AS DateTime) AS EndDate
```

then using this expression in SSRS:

```
=DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Fields!StartDate.Value, Fields!EndDate.Value)
```

still yields 9 days, even when using a time component. Try the following expression:

```
=DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, DateTime.Today, Fields!EndDate.Value)
```

Are you displaying the date fields to make sure what you think you should get is what you actually get? For instance, make sure you aren't being returned cached data.

Comment: DATEDIFF(DAY, TODAY(), TARGET FINISH(TARGETFINISH))

--- This formula i have written for a new field that i have created within Report Builder. There is no other way i can write this formula.

///DAY - an arguement and can be written like this only. There is no other way.
///TODAY() - I have taken this from date-time function available in report builder to get current date.
///TARGET FINISH(TARGETFINISH) - This is a column in table from which i am taking the value.

----This whole formula gives me wrong calculation. Instead of 9 gives output as 10.

Please help!!

Comment: Just to clear things ---- I am defining Formula in Report Builder not writing an expression in ssrs.